# Tag deletion request: [tools]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

As of right now, the [tools](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools) tag has 18 questions, 5 of which have been closed (mostly due to asking for tool recommendations).  This is not a tag that anyone would favorite or use for searching, so I'm recommending it be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no more questions in [tools](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools), so it looks like this is settled.